# Is it possible to make a button in a guitar which when tapped can connect to bluetooth speaker?

Tags: guitar

can an aqoustic guitar be connected to speaker thru bluetooth? we were talking about innovations and a friend comes up with an idea of an acoustic guitar being connected to speakers through bluetooth by just tapping a button on a guitar. is it possible?

Comment: Google 'bluetooth guitar'. Be amazed. Bog standard acoustic - not yet!

Comment: I have no experience with bluetooth guitar adapters, but sometimes bluetooth introduces a noticeable delay on the signal that makes it hard to play.

Comment: My Bluetooth audio experience has always been very high latency. Up to several seconds. I can’t imagine trying to play guitar over Bluetooth, but maybe the latest standards are much faster than what I’m used to.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking *is* certainly possible, but I personally don't think it'll be replacing regular cables any time soon.

As some of the comments have stated already, there are a number of problems to keep in mind. Latency will probably be the biggest factor to deal with, because once the audio coming out of the amp is happening later than when you are strumming, it becomes really difficult to play. Certainly if the latency is worse than 20ms, then the audio will be happening noticeably late. Then do you play just a bit ahead of the drums that you hear, or the bass? Playing through delay like that is not a very tenable situation.

I've had a number of different wireless audio devices in my time, and they all have some quirks that would need to be polished in order to satisfy guitar players that are very mindful of their tone. I have a set of bluetooth wireless headphones which stutter if they move too quickly in relation to the receiver, and you definitely don't want something like that happening in the middle of a set.

*In favor* of working wireless guitar solutions, I can say that I've been to a show where the lead guitarist had some sort of wireless setup between his guitar and amp. In the middle of the set, the guy just started walking through the crowd, and right out the door of the bar to the parking lot. His band mates looked ticked off, but kept playing, and he eventually wandered back. All the while, I didn't perceive any delay between his playing and the audio I was listening to, but I also am not sure what technology that wireless system was using.

One point that probably does not come up much is security (I do computer security related work, so I think about it a lot). Once you start involving wireless signals, there's almost always some sort of authentication and/or other security in place to prevent people from tampering with the data that's being transmitted. Bluetooth has a [history of security concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#History_of_security_concerns), and [WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Network_security) is [in the same boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_security). Keeping your wireless signal free from passive or possibly malicious interference is another task on to-do list here.

Overall, there are *a lot* of problems that need to be overcome with wireless audio, in order to make it perform as well as regular guitar cables do. That, coupled with the fact that regular guitar cables are ubiquitous (imagine an amp or a pedal without a 1/4" jack on it) and relatively cheap, makes cables the go-to solution for most people.

Comment: There would have been a latency between his playing and that of the band, due to him being in quite a different physical place. I used to use wireless in certain venues, due mainly to picking up mains hum (50Hz) if I used cables. It sorted out that problem, with no delay. Back in the '90s.